# Angular use a service provided in a shared module not recognizing the injectable

Tags: angular

Meet SharedModule, it is importing and exporting several modules:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PlatformSwitchPageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyApiModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MyApiModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

`MyApiModule` is another module that contains a few modules related to my Api:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FileChunkUploaderModule,
    FileDownloaderModule,
    SessionClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    FileChunkUploaderModule,
    FileDownloaderModule,
    SessionClientModule
  ]
})
export class MyApiModule{ }
```

Now, `SessionClientModule` is a module that provides a service:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [SessionClient],
})
export class SessionClientModule {
}
```

**Now you can't really export a service, since it's not a pipe or a directive or a component.**

So here comes the `PagesModule` which contains the pages of the application, where each page is a module of on its own:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LandingModule,
    SharedModule,
    ExampleModule
  ],
  exports: [
    LandingModule,
    ExampleModule
  ]
})
export class PagesModule { }
```

Now, `PageaModule` is imported in AppModule and is used in the router for lazy-loading by routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LandingComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'session/:id',
    component: ExampleModule
  }
];
```

In `ExampleModule` I provide a service called `MyService`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ExampleComponent, DesktopFileTransferLayoutComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [MyService],
  exports: [ExampleComponent]
})
export class ExampleModule { }
```

and MyService injects in itself `SessionClient` service which is part of `SessionClientModule` exported in `MyApiModule` which is exported in `SharedModule`.

Now I get the following error when using it:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[MyService -> SessionClient -> SessionClient -> SessionClient]:
```

If `SharedModule` is imported in `PagesModule`, why doesn't it recognize the service I am trying to use?

**Latest version of angular**

Comment: The service itself. What does it look like. does it have `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
` ?

Comment: Just @Injectable() defaults

Comment: See the answer by @Zerotwelve the modern, default way is this. The older way is to provide it in the app-module. Same effect. Generally you will want services to be singletons. If you do not you can provide them locally. [Frontend Decoded](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLX7eV3JL9sfmJ6AaZj9eDlAKrJrEul4Vz) y outube channel is an excellent resource to learn more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you create a service with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` you don't need to declare the service in any `providers` and it will be avaliable everywhere  (just add it in the constructor)

Comment: Isn't there a way to provide it only when the module is used, and not globally?

Comment: yes, but you really need that?
This makes only sense if you want to use multiple instances of the service (and not as a singleton)

  https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules

Comment: Well in my current case no, should always be singleton shared across the application, but I may end up in a case where there should be a new instance every time, I would love to know how to do it.

Comment: if you need a new instance every time, then you can create a normal typescript class (and not a service) like `this.myCar = new Car()` but if you want to share the service only inside certain modules/ have one instance per module you can do as described in the angular documentation (see comment above)

Comment: If I create the instance myself, I can't inject in other services

Comment: true, but it can be an option when you need a new instance every time (always creates a new instance) or you can pass it as an input to other components if you want to share it. It's just a reminder that services are not mandatory, sometimes there are alternatives

Comment: I know that in like in every DI container, there is an option to put the service in a non-singleton scope, create new instance everytime which will create the whole tree of the class injections, just never done it with angular, I did with Nestjs and with inversify too